# Extract XML properties in a bash script based on other property

Tags: xml, bash, sed

I haven't written bash in a very long time and I'm trying to come up with the best solution to this problem. I think sed or awk will be the used but I'm not sure how.

I have this xml file:

```
<Projects>
  <Project Guid="46824750-4e2d-46bd-bb6d-7c229cde63d5" Name="Example 1" Type="1" LastModified="2020-09-28T20:44:35.36Z" Version="36.0" />
  <Project Guid="d1137da2-041c-1f3e-a92b-48b2db9663c8" Name="Example 2" Type="5" LastModified="2020-03-24T21:19:48.517Z" Version="5.0" />
  <Project Guid="46824750-4c2d-49c5-8a6c-2c229cff63d5" Name="Example 3" Type="2" LastModified="2020-01-03T18:14:05.047Z" Version="3.2" />
</Projects>
```

In a bash script, I need to find the line that contains Type="1", and extract that Guid from the same line. Note only one  in each xml file will contain Type="1". Can sed be used for this? Or would I have to go an xml parsing route?

I can't really install extra dependencies or libraries since this is running on Jenkins agent and the process to get dependencies approved is long and strict. This would ideally be done with built in Bash/UNIX functionality.

Any ideas on the best approach to this?

Comment: If this code is going into production I would very strongly suggest using `xsltproc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although not the best tool for the job, sed *can* be used. Please try

```sh
sed -n '/Type="1"/s/.*Guid="\([^"]*\).*/\1/p' file.xml
```

Tested with GNU sed 4.8

Comment: What would be better? I only need something that can reliably execute this very specific use case, nothing more

Comment: A designated XML tool like `xmlstarlet` is usually recommended whenever handling XML, but in this case the `sed` solution is adequate.